# Alternative to inferring types from unconsumed generic parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript file with entity information auto-generated from the server entity model. For each entity type, the file contains a TypeScript interface and metadata.

Simplified example with one entity:

```
// Auto-generated

interface Report {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

interface ReportEntityType extends EntityType<Report> {
    properties: {
        id: Property<number>;
        title: Property<string>;
    }
}

var entityTypes = {
    Report: <ReportEntityType>{
        properties: {
            id: {
                dataType: "number"
            },
            title: {
                dataType: "string",
                required: true,
                displayName: "Title"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For completeness, here are the referenced interfaces (also simplified):

```
interface EntityType<T> {
    properties: any;
}

interface Property<T> {
    dataType: string;
    required?: boolean;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Thoughout the project, the `Report` interface is used at compile time for type checking and intellisense, and the `entityTypes.Report` metadata object is used at both compile and runtime for various purposes. For example, `displayName` is used to render a label for the property, and `required` is used for validation.

**How can I get TypeScript to infer the type `Report` from the type `ReportEntityType`?**

Example:

```
class Validator<TEntityType> {
    constructor(entityType: EntityType<TEntityType>) { }

    validate(obj: TEntityType) { }
}

var validator = new Validator(entityTypes.Report);
```

Currently, TypeScript will infer that `validator` is a `Validator<{}>`, but I want it to infer that it is `Validator<Report>`.

Based on comments from the TypeScript team [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/360) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1396), the problem is that my `EntityType<T>` interface does not use the `T` parameter itself:

> I'm thinking unconsumed generic type parameters in general to be an error
>
> Do not define generic types that don't use the type parameter type

Fair enough. Interestingly, all I have to do is add a `dummy?: T;` property to `EntityType<T>` and it works. I want to avoid this hack, and instead implement this in an idiomatic TypeScript way. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A simplified example :

```
interface Report{}
interface EntityType<T> {
    properties: any; // Change to T and it works
}
interface ReportEntity extends EntityType<Report>{}

var rep1:EntityType<Report>;
var rep2:ReportEntity;

class Validator<TEntityType> {
    constructor(entityType: EntityType<TEntityType>) { }
}

var val1 = new Validator(rep1); // okay 
var val2 = new Validator(rep2); // Not okay
```

The issue here is that in the absence of you using `T` in `EntityType`, `rep2` is effectively `EntityType<{}>`. So no good solution exists other than to use `T` || not use the extended interface (see `rep1`).